# How to reset chosen class li elements using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I need some help. I need to reset all `li` elements again which are auto created by `chosen-select` jQuery plug-in.

```
<link href="css/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<div class="popover-content">
<p>                            
<select class="chosen-select text-left" style="width:100%;"  onchange="setCountry();" id="conid">
<option value="" selected>Select Country</option>
<?php
foreach ($country as $v) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $v['country_id']; ?>"><?php echo $v['country_name']; ?></option>
    <?php
 }
?>
</select>
</p>
</div>
<div id="popupcity" class="popover" style="width:270px">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<h3 class="popover-title">Select City</h3>
<div class="popover-content" id="ctchoosen">
<p>                            
<select class="text-left" style="width:100%;" id="ctid" onchange="setCity();">
<option value="" selected>Select City</option>
</select>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

When the user selects the country, the city values will be added into the city select list.

```
function setCountry(){
        var conval=document.getElementById('conid');
        var selectVal='';
        if (conval.selectedIndex == -1){
            return null;
        }else{
            selectVal=conval.options[conval.selectedIndex].text;
            $("#popupcountry").removeClass("in");
        }
        document.getElementById('bindCon').innerHTML=selectVal;
        $('#borderCon').css('border', '');
        //console.log('contr',conval.options[conval.selectedIndex].value);
        var url="common.php?action=getCity";
        $.post(url,{"con_data":conval.options[conval.selectedIndex].value},function(data){
            var obj=JSON.parse(data);
            console.log('data1',obj);
            var ctData='';
            $('#ctid').find('option').not(':first').remove();
            $('#ctid').removeClass('chosen-select');
            $('.chosen-select').chosen();
            if(obj.isData==1){
                ctData=obj.cid;
                $.each(ctData, function(idx, o) {

                    $("#ctid").append("<option value="+o.city_id+">"+o.city_name+"</option>");
                    //$("#ctchoosen > ul").append('<li class="active-result" data-option-array-index='+this.city_id+'>'+this.city_name+'</li>');
                })
                $('#ctid').addClass('chosen-select');
                $('.chosen-select').chosen();
            }
        })
      }
```

When the user selects any option in the country select list, the cities are appending and I need the cities in the select box/auto created list item elements to update.

I can reset the select box but am unable to reset the auto created list item elements for which when user is selecting any new country the cities belongs to this is not displaying to user. I am also using PHP for the database operations.

Comment: Where is the unordered list (i.e. `<ul></ul>`) in the markup? Is it supposed to be under `<div class="popover-content" id="ctchoosen">`? Is there supposed to be code to remove the existing list items in that list when updating the cities?

Comment: its auto-creating  by the class `chosen-select`.

Comment: Yes sir,Please see my code in the post.I have mentioned avobe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chosen offers an event that can be triggered. From [the documentation](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events):

> - #### Updating Chosen Dynamically
>
>   If you need to update the options in your select field and want Chosen to pick up the changes, you'll need to trigger the "*chosen:updated*" event on the field. Chosen will re-build itself based on the updated content.
>
>   ```
>   $("#form_field").trigger("chosen:updated");
>   ```
>
>   <sup>[1](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events)</sup>

When the city list has options, instead of just calling

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen();
```

after adding the cities, trigger the updated event on it:

```
$('#ctid').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

See a demonstration of this below.

```js
//track whether options have been added to the list 
var cityOptionsAdded = false;

function setCountry() {
  var conval = document.getElementById('conid');
  var selectVal = '';
  if (conval.selectedIndex == -1) {
    return null;
  } else {
    selectVal = conval.options[conval.selectedIndex].text;
    $("#popupcountry").removeClass("in");
  }
  $('#borderCon').css('border', '');
  var url = conval.options[conval.selectedIndex].value + ".json";
  $.post(url, function(obj) {
    var ctData = '';
    $('#ctid').find('option').not(':first').remove();
    $('#ctid').removeClass('chosen-select');
    chosenSelect = $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    if (obj.isData == 1) {
      ctData = obj.cid;
      $.each(ctData, function(idx, o) {

        $("#ctid").append("<option value=" + o.city_id + ">" + o.city_name + "</option>");
      });
      if (cityOptionsAdded) { //subsequent addition of cities to list
        $('#ctid').trigger("chosen:updated");
      } else { //first time adding cities to list
        cityOptionsAdded = true;
        $('#ctid').addClass('chosen-select');
        chosenSelect = $('.chosen-select').chosen();
      }
    }
  });
}
/**override jQuery ajax for this sandbox
  because real AJAX requests are disabled 
  in this environment
*/
$.post = function(url, callback) {
  var data;
  if ($('#conid').val() == 'CA') {
    data = {
      "isData": true,
      "cid": [{
        "city_id": "OT",
        "city_name": "Ottowa"
      }, {
        "city_id": "VA",
        "city_name": "Vancouver"
      }]
    };
  }
  if ($('#conid').val() == 'SE') {
    data = {
      "isData": true,
      "cid": [{
        "city_id": "ST",
        "city_name": "Stockholm"
      }, {
        "city_id": "LU",
        "city_name": "Lund"
      }]
    };
  }
  callback(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.min.css" />
<div class="popover-content">
  <p>
    <select class="chosen-select text-left" style="width:100%;" onchange="setCountry()" id="conid">
        <option value="" selected>Select Country</option>
        <option value="CA">Canada</option>
        <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
      </select>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="popupcity" class="popover" style="width:270px">
  <div class="arrow"></div>
  <h3 class="popover-title">Select City</h3>
  <div class="popover-content" id="ctchoosen">
    <p>
      <select class="text-left" style="width:100%;" id="ctid">
          <option value="" selected>Select City</option>
        </select>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events</sub>